# Cannot visualize html page with white background: background is forced to black

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Using Google Chrome (or Microsoft Edge) on Windows 11, I cannot visualize a very simple HTML page with a white background.

If you try to visualize the following page with Edge, the background will always be black:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
              body { background-color: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        TEST
    </body>
</html>
```

If I set `background-color: red`, the background will be red, as expected.

Firefox has the page displayed correctly in all cases.

How to display a page with a white background?

Answer (score 0):

I think that because you are using a corrupted chrome or edge ,Try to reinstall them, or use the `sfc/scannow` ,that should fix all corrupted file, from them the web browsers' too like what I think. Try that and see.

Comment: I tried on 3 different computers, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. On all my computers I use the `force dark` setting for both Chrome and Edge. This setting causes all web pages not having explicit support for dark mode to render as if they were using dark mode:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark
```

If I restore the default value for this setting (`Default` instead of `Enabled`), the background can indeed be white.